# Formatting multiple char* strings to an std::string

Tags: c++

I have two char* strings and a char* literal that I need to combine into a single std::string.  Below is what I am doing.  It works, but I don't like the way it looks (3 lines to accomplish it).  I am wondering if there is a better way to do it...

```
std::string strSource = _szImportDirectory;
strSource += "\\";
strSource += _szImportSourceFile;
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::string strSource = std::string(_szImportDirectory) + "\\" + _szImportSourceFile;
```

Is one obvious way.

Another way is to use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << _szImportDirectory << '\\' + _szImportSourceFile;
std::string strSource = s.str()
```

That's the most flexible and maintainable way to do it but it still requires three lines.

Comment: Thanks. I think if I had a large number of char*'s to combine (which I often do) then the stringstream solution becomes more efficient. I'm going to go with that one for now.  And now that I think about it, with the stringstream I can also incorpate int's and anything else that is sendable to a cout, I would assume.  That's definitely what I wanted.

Comment: Seth, not really related to the problem at hand, but if I had a stringstream and wanted to get a char* from it, can I get it directly from the stringstream somehow? Or do I get a std::string and then c_str() it?

Comment: @John yeah, you need to call `str()` to "materialize" the string, then `c_str()` to get the pointer to it. I would save the string that it returns from `str()` though if you can use it again, because it's not an inexpensive operation.

Comment: @Seth: You need to save the `string` from `str` or the memory pointed to by `c_str` will be deallocated.

Comment: @Bill oh ok thanks, I thought it would be owned by the stringstream.

Comment: @Seth: when you do s.str() you get a newly allocated string.  If you don't capture it then it deallocates at the end the statement.  In `char* cptr = s.str().c_str();`, the temporary only lasts until `;`, so the memory `c_str()` points to is no longer valid by the time you can use `cptr`.  If you're passing the result to another function, like `strcpy` or some other function that expects a null-terminated `char*`, then you're OK as long as it doesn't store the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
std::string str = std::string(_szImportDirectory).append("\\").append(_szImportSourceFile);
```

**PS: updated with correct code**

Comment: BTW, looks like Java StringBuffer style :)

Comment: Which is a good thing.  Truth be told, I really miss all the Java conveniences when working with strings in C++.  (Do downvoted comments affect my reputation?)

Comment: `String s = strImportDir + "\\" + strImportFile; s.replace("some Regular Expression", "b"); if (s.match("\$\{hi\}") { /* etc */ }; /* Actually I know I can do this all with std::string, but I'm still learning it all */`

Comment: Oh and I forgot my favorite `String[] a = s.split(",");`

Comment: Alf, you're right. The correct version is: `std::string str = std::string(_szImportDirectory).append("\\").append(_szImportSourceFile);`

Comment: Sorry it was stream-of-consciousness code.  match() should have been matches() and the backslashes in it should have been doubled.  Anyway, I am sure I will find the equivalents for std::string.

Comment: John, for regexes you can use std::tr1 extension or boost::regex.

Comment: Thanks Vitaly I will investigate those.  I'm getting the feeling boost is indispensable.